# Break PHP into 3 columns and display one by one

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to break a PHP array into 3 columns (has to be columns, not rows) so it would look something like this:

```
Item 1     Item 5     Item 9
Item 2     Item 6     Item 10
Item 3     Item 7    Item 11..............
Item 4     Item 8
```

Comment: is this a tabular data? just use tables, then design it with CSS to your heart's content

Comment: Unsure what you wish to accomplish. Are you talking about building table columns in HTML?

Comment: I am able to display like this..                                                               Item 1     Item 2     Item 3
Item 4     Item 5     Item 6
Item 7    Item 8   Item 9
Item 10     Item 11.....  but i  am unable to display like above..

Comment: may i know how many rows you want? for the one column?

Comment: You need only three columns or can it be more

Comment: are you fetching data from database?

Comment: s i am fetching data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Update to Meldin answer

```
$cols = 3; // Number of columns
$len = ceil(count($items) / $cols);
echo '<ul class="floatleft">';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    if ($i % $len == 0)
        echo '</ul><ul class="floatleft">';
    echo "<li>" . $items[$i] . "</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Also you can try this using two foreach() loops

```
$len = ceil(count($items)/3);
$itm = array_chunk($items,$len,true);

foreach($itm as $cols){
    echo '<div class="floatleft">';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($cols as $col){
        echo '<li>'.$col.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo '<ul class="floatleft">';
for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){
  if($i%4==0)
    echo '</ul><ul class="floatleft">';
  echo "<li>".$items[$i]."</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: note: you need to specify the class floatleft with float:left; and you should add to parent element something like [this](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) or it won't have a height..

Comment: @Meldin: the columns will increase more than 3 and each column will have only 4 items

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$total = 10;
$cols = 3;
$rows = ceil($total/$cols);
echo "<table>";
for($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
   echo "<tr>"; 
   for($j = 1; $j <= $cols; $j++) {
        $value = $i + 4*($j-1);
        if ($value <= $total) {
            echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
        }
    }
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```